# Disable colours on terminal and SSH

Tags: ssh, terminal, colors

My local Linux machine has coloured terminal output like this;

[image]

When I SSH to a pfSense/BSD box it changes the colours like this;

[image]

Even when I SSH from to a machine that doesn't have a coloured local terminal output, and SSH from there to this pfSense/FreeBSD box it enables coloured output, and starts producing unwanted coloured output/

Is there something I can change locally so that when I SSH to the pfSense box from either my local machine or via an intermediary machine, my client will ignore the remote colour settings. Ideally I want to stay in black and white, two tone standard background and text colour only?

Comment: What terminal application are you using?

Comment: Here I am running Mint Linux 13, so it's Xfce Terminal Emulator 0.4.8.

Comment: I know this isn't what you are asking for, but have you considered changing your terminal settings to white [or light gray] text on a black background? That is the basic color scheme that most things are designed to work with. Or you could change your prompt settings on the remote machine (probably in .bash_profile) to have better colors or no colors at all.

Comment: Normally I do something like `TERM=xterm-mono ssh user@host` to get that setting in the remote environment.

Answer (score 9):

Changing the `TERM` variable to some entry that is compatible but doesn't have colour support might work. Like:

```
TERM=xterm-old
```

Basically, you need a `TERM` known by the FreeBSD system termcap or terminfo database for which `TERM=the-term tput colors` doesn't return a positive number, and for GNU ls, one for which `dircolors -p | grep -x 'TERM the-term'` returns nothing. It may still not work for applications that output colour escape sequences regardless of whether the terminal claims to support it or not.

Alternatively, you could use GNU `screen` to disable colors, like (zsh syntax):

```
screen -c =(printf %s\\n "termcapinfo * 'AF=\E[1m:AB=\E[7m'") ssh ...
```

That would enable *bold* for every attempt to set the foreground colour and *reverse* for every attempt to set the background one.

I think it all boils down to the fact that FreeBSD assumes that the terminal background is black (or at least dark). Where you using `xterm` instead of `xfce-terminal`, you could dynamically change the background and foreground colour and/or the individual colours to set different colour profiles. That is done through escape sequences, but you can also use the `xtermcontrol` command that makes it easier.

Comment: Tried that - doesn't work for me. `export TERM=vt100` preceding `ls --color` still shows colorized output.

Comment: @gertvdijk Good point. It seem there's a bug in GNU ls which by default hard codes `vt100` as being a terminal with colour support. I've changed that do `xterm-old` which doesn't have that problem but might not have a terminfo entry on FreeBSD.

Comment: Well, it doesn't prevent other programs from outputting colour as well - i.e. `byobu`. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 btw.

Comment: @gertvdijk. Like I said. It only works for well behaved programs that use `$TERM` and the termcap/terminfo databases (via curses or other terminal APIs) instead of hardcoding the escape sequences.

Comment: what can i use to remove all escape sequences that can change terminal state after EOF?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen Some suggestions at https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream

Answer (score 8):

Colours in your terminal appear because the tty sends ANSI-encoded control sequences to tell your terminal to change colours. Some, if not most terminal application can be configured to ignore this and just display all text in one colour.

In `xterm`, you can use the `-cm` option. For Konsole, one can change the mapping of all colours to the same. Your XFCE terminal application may have similar options.

Comment: This answer may help in some cases, but it is not really an answer. As mentioned "Colours in your terminal appear because the tty sends ANSI-encoded control sequences to tell your terminal to change colours". As SSH may provide TTY, it should also be possible for SSH to ignore colors. Any idea how this is done?

Comment: SSH is not designed to interfere with the data over the tty, really. SSH sets up a channel on which you can run it, I don't think it *should* ever involve in altering data over that channel. It does, however, provides context and metadata, such as which environment variables are passed from client to server during setup time of such a channel.

Answer (score 2):

Type the following command to remove it:

```
$ ls --color=none
```

or use `unalias` to remove it:

```
$ unalias ls
```

Comment: Isn't that just for the `ls` commad though?

Comment: ls is aliased to "ls --color=tty"

Comment: Yes. I know. But all my terminal output is coloured output, not just the `ls` command, so as per my previous comment: isn't that just going to stop `ls` producing coloured output, everything else will still be coloured though?

Comment: yes only the ls portion

Comment: But I want to disable all terminal colours?!

Comment: are you using xterm? xterm -cm

Comment: or you can try this Add the following lines to your ~/.bash_profile

export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to modify your ~/.bashrc which I'm sure contain something like `export PS2=.....+colors......` :

On the linux Console, try either `TERM=linux-m1b` or `TERM=linux-m2` to get monochrome as "Gray/White/Black and Dim" for linux-m1b or "Green/White/Black and Blue" (vintage!) for linux-m2 ...

With Putty (there is a port for Mac users), use `TERM=putty-m1b` and `TERM=putty-m2` instead ...

This will do exactly what you need but:
You'll need a recent terminfo database for that or get it from there if necessary: `wget http://canal.chez.com/linux.ti ; tic -x linux.ti`

Alex.
PS: xterm-mono seems not to exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to convince your terminal emulator and environment that it cannot support colors in the first place, presuming your GNU/Linux system is not ignoring the rules:

```
unset LS_COLORS
TERM=xterm-mono
export TERM
```

Try using `TERM=vt100` or `TERM=xterm-mono` in something like `htop` and you should immediately see the difference.

You could also quickly test by trying to toggle colors in `top` by pressing lowercase `z`.

---

Alternately, by combining some other contributors methods, you could get a list of "no-color" terminal definitions (-1) and pick one:

```
$ find /lib/terminfo -type f -exec sh -c 'for fx do T=`basename "$fx"` ;echo -n "$T ";TERM=$T tput colors ;done' find-sh {} + | sort -V | grep '\-1'
```

```
dumb -1
mach -1
mach-bold -1
mach-gnu -1
rxvt-basic -1
sun -1
vt52 -1
vt100 -1
vt102 -1
vt220 -1
xterm-mono -1
xterm-r5 -1
xterm-r6 -1
```

Comment: That won't work, because `dircolors  -p` uses globs, e.g., `xterm*` which match anything usable in `/lib/terminfo`.

Comment: Eh?  It seems to work on this end. But if anyone would know, then you would.  I guess I just got lucky.  Is there a recommended way around it?

Comment: Actually "vt220" looks promising (though function-keys may be a problem).

Comment: I wonder if it appears to work on this end because I "unset LS_COLORS" out of habit?  Either way, I will take your lead and default to TERM=vt220  now and see how it goes.

Answer (score -2):

First, check your default alias:

```
alias

alias ls-'ls --color=auto
```

If the doesn't work and you need a quick workaround.  Try this `ls` and `awk` pipe:

```
vi /usr/local/bin/list
#!/bin/bash
ls $1
exit
```

set the perms `744`.
One safe place for this would be `/usr/local/bin`
Make sure your PATH includes `/usr/local/bin`.

Again use discretion.

One thing… the colors are meant to flag directories… 
turning off the `ls="ls --color=auto"` leaves only names… 
`ls -aF` or `ls -F` will append the directory names with `/`.  So I would suggest that  you be aware.   You could `alias ls="ls -aF"` or `alias ls="ls -F"`.

Comment: How does this answer provide an answer to the original question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: To the parts that this doesn't duplicate existing answers, it is simply wrong (ranging from robustness problems to outright invalid syntax).